# Redundant results when printing ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   public class Apple {
        private static String color;
        private static int weight;
        public Apple(String color, int weight){
            this.color = color;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
        public int getWeight(){
            return weight;
        }
        public String getColor(){
        return color;
        }
        public interface AppleFormatter{
            String accept(Apple a);
        }
        public static class AppleFancyFormatter implements AppleFormatter{
            public String accept(Apple apple){
                String characteristic = apple.getWeight() > 150 ? "heavy" :     "light";
                return "A " + characteristic + " " + apple.getColor() + "  apple";
            }
        }
        public static class AppleSimpleFormatter implements AppleFormatter{
            public String accept(Apple apple){
                return "An apple of " + apple.getWeight() + "g";
            }
        } 
        public static void prettyPrintApple(List<Apple> inventory,  AppleFormatter formatter){
            for(Apple apple: inventory){
                String output = formatter.accept(apple);
                System.out.println(output);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            List<Apple> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            Apple app1 = new Apple("green", 155);
            Apple app2 = new Apple("yellow", 160);
            Apple app3 = new Apple("red", 130);
            arrayList.add(app1);
            arrayList.add(app2);
            arrayList.add(app3);

            prettyPrintApple(arrayList, new AppleFancyFormatter());
            prettyPrintApple(arrayList, new AppleSimpleFormatter());

        }
    }
```

The following code prints:
A light red apple
A light red apple
A light red apple
An apple of 130g
An apple of 130g
An apple of 130g

Ive noticed a tendency for my arrays not to iterate properly but intstead the last object I created gets printed continously. I dont know why this is. What am I missing?`enter code here`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fields are static!!

```
 private static String color;
 private static int weight;
```

So all apples share the same color and weight! Remove the static keyword and every thing works fine!